# Is it okay to ask for a hint to a problem that had already been solved here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, hint

I am trying to prove a certain proposition on my own, and I got stuck.

I have the proof somewhere in my lecture notes, and the proposition had been proved here in some question on this site, but I do not want to see the solution because it's important for me to do it on my own.

A peek on the proof might be too much revealing, so I am looking for a tiny hint in order to complete the work.

Is it okay to ask for a hint to a problem that had already been solved here on the site?

Answer (score 6):

I think if you try really hard, you'll be able to peek at the proof without spoiling it for yourself. Even if you posted asking for a hint, you will probably get answers from hapless responders who reveal too much to suit you, or are otherwise unable to control themselves based on your requirement.

So, there does not seem to be a lot to be gained by making a new post this way. You're better off regulating yourself as you read, or else maybe asking a friend to give a hint based on a solution. Both options seem a lot simpler than the process of reposting.